# Error when static linking g++

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, gcc, static-linking

I have a problem, i want to compile my application with static linking of mysql connector.

My command line:

> g++  -o newserver  stdafx.cpp ... -lboost_system -lboost_thread
>   -lpthread -lmysqlcppconn -static /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a -std=c++0x

But i have error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
/tmp/ccxpOfdZ.o: In function `IsEqualsDns(unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
Server.cpp:(.text+0x356e): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the library `libsqlcppconn.a` or `libsqucppconn.so`
(static or dynamic)?  The compiler is looking for it, and
doesn't find it.

Presumably, this is the same library as
`/usr/lib/mysqlcppconn-static.a`.  If so, just drop the
`-lmysqlcppconn`.  Or just use `-lmysqlcppconn-static` (no
spaces), and forget about the `/usr/lib/libmysqlconn-static.a`.
With a name like that, there shouldn't be a corresponding `.so`,
which means that g++ will link it statically, even without the
`-static`.  You only need the `-static` if there is both
a `libmysqlconn-static.so` and a `libmysqlconn-static.a` in the
same directory.

With regards to the second error (which is just a warning, but
will cause problems if you try to run the linked program on
other machines, or even after an upgrade of your machine): if
you use `-static` anywhere in your command line (as you
currently do), then it applies to all files linked afterwards.
Including the system libraries, which you *don't* want to link
statically.  My guess is that the `-static` isn't necessary (see
above); if it is, place it immediately before the library you
want to link statically, and place a `-dynamic` immediately
after (so that any following libraries, including the system
libraries, will be dynamically linked).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `g++ -static YOUR ARGUMENTS`.

If you are coming from a Windows platform, linking against Boost can give a few surprises. The typicall Boost installation (e.g. after `./b2 install`) will make both dynamic and static libraries and put them in the same directory. Typically, the two library forms only differ in their extension (.so or .a).

Windows supports **auto-linking**, which basically means that library files contain some flags in their first few bytes indicating whether they are for dynamic or for static linking. On Linux platforms, this is not the case and the linker gets confused which file to load (since you don't provide the extension of the library name). Therefore, you need to tell your linker which form of linking you want.

Comment: That won't help him to find a library which isn't there.  (And I don't think the missing library is part of Boost.)  If he does want to link Boost statically (and IMHO, he should), then `-static` before the `-l` for the Boost libraries, _and_ `-dynamic` after the last library he wants to link statically (because you don't want to link the system libraries statically---that's the reason for the warning).

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, tnx. Your answer should be selected as the correct one. Should I remove this one?

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove it.  It provides useful additional information, even if it doesn't address the immediate issue.